# Why is sweetalert2 not working in my code?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, sweetalert2

I read the documentation carefully
But it doesn't work again!!

The function of "back(req, res)" is only to return to the previous page

```
const Swal = require("sweetalert2");

exports.getAboutMe = (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    back(req, res);
    Swal.fire("Any fool can use a computer");
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
}
```

I put a button for this route and when I click on the button, it leads me to this code